# Finding all duplicates in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested, duplicates

I'm taking a beginners class in Java Programming. I'm trying to write a program that finds and prints out the duplicates in an array. This is what I have so far. I'm stuck. I'm thinking I need an `else` statement after the `if`?

```
public class Array {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N=10;        
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
      {
        if(i == j)
        {              
          System.out.println("Both arrays contain " + i);              
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong. What is your question?

Comment: Where is your array?

Comment: Looking at the related questions, I see at least three that this one could be a duplicate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test15 {
  static int[] a = new int[]{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5};
  public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int i=0; i< a.length; i++) {
      boolean f = false;
      for (int j=i+1; j <a.length; j++)
        if (a[i]==a[j]) {
          System.out.println("duplicate ("+i+", "+j+")");
          f=true;
          break;
        }
      if (!f)
        System.out.println("unique ("+i+", "+a[i]+")");
    }
  }
}
```